# How to set the context of a Dynamic Expression

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to build dynamic expression which I don't know its structure at compile time but I know how to parse it

```
var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");    
var lambda = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new[] { x }, typeof(bool), expression);
```

Where `expression` is a runtime string that can be for example

```
x.Id > 1
```

Now I have a more complex task I want to achieve

```
x => ListOfIds.Contains(x.Id)
```

I want to bind a value to the `ListOfIds` which I don't know how or where it will be available in the expression since it's dynamic and the function will only accept one argument (basically I want to feed the expression to a Linq where method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`?

It seems that you are looking for their [Substitution Values](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions#substitution-values) functionality, in order to provide an object as a constant expression to the lambda that is generated.

The following code should work for you:

```
var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var constantExpressions = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"ListOfIds", ListOfIds}
};
var lambda = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new[] { x }, typeof(bool), "ListOfIds.Contains(x.Id)", constantExpressions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this from Github https://github.com/PoweredSoft/DynamicLinq

Or Nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/PoweredSoft.DynamicLinq/

This class library allows you to do

```
var ageGroup = new List<int>() { 28, 27, 50 };
Persons.AsQueryable().Query(t => t.In("Age", ageGroup));
```

You can take a look at https://github.com/PoweredSoft/DynamicLinq/blob/master/PoweredSoft.DynamicLinq/Helpers/QueryableHelpers.cs#L234 if you wish to see the source code taking care of it.

Hope this can help